# Whack a mole game with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a whack-a-mole game for a school assignment and I can't get it to work.

The full code can be found on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lc30u5h7/5/) to make this question shorter.

Whenever I load the code my "moles" (black square divs) disappear. By turning parts of my code in to comments I nailed down the error to this part of the code:

```
function showMole(tile) {
        if (gameRunning) {
            $(this).css({"background-color": "green"});
            $(tile).data('mole', true);
            randomInt(400, 1200) {hideMole(this)};
        };
};
function hideMole(tile) {
        $(tile).css({"background-color": "black"});
        $(tile).data('mole', false);
        randomInt(4000,48000) {showMole(this)};
};
```

More specifically the error is located witht the function randomInt() which uses the following code:

```
function randomInt(min, max){
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
};
```

The functions are supposed to represent the different states of the moles. After a random interval a mole will switch from hideMole() to showMole() and it will turn green and reward a point if clicked (which is handled by another piece of code).

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: From a quick look: I guess it's because `randomInt(4000,48000) {hideMole(this)};`  is not doing what you're expecting it to. What this says is basically `,<someNumber>{hideMole(this)}`. Therefore hideMole is always executed. Also, there are syntax errors in your jsfiddle. Also divs usually require content to be shown, at least `&nbsp;`. Maybe take it a bit slower and go step by step, verifying every single one?

Comment: To add to what @t.animal said, change this syntax `hideMole(".this")` to `hideMole(this)`. you can look at api examples [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: @t.animal empty `<div>` is a non problem. Used them for years cross browser with no issues

Comment: @charlietfl you're right. &nbsp; is not needed when height and width are set.

Comment: @t.animal I found the site JSHint which helped me fix the syntax errors, so the first problem is fixed and I changed the post accordingly. Do you know a way to solve the problem with randomInt()?

Comment: randomInt() is going to give you a number and that is not a function so as @t.animal says, it is not doing what you expect.  You likely want setTimeout() and/or setInterval().  See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get you started with some example code.  This code uses a handful of times to help manage the game.

```js
var game = function() {
  var gameBoard_Selector = "#gameBoard";
  var tile_Selector = ".tile";
  var mole_ClassName = "mole";

  var $gameBoard = $(gameBoard_Selector);
  var $gameTiles = $gameBoard.find(tile_Selector);

  var gameTime = 20 * 1000;
  var turnTime = 1000;

  var moleInterval;
  var moleLifeMin = 1000;
  var moleLifeMax = 3 * 1000;

  var gameScore = 0;

  var getRandomIntInclusive = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  // ------------------------
  // Add a click handler to the board
  // This could be added and removed at start and end as an alternative.
  // or added to each individual tile if you liked that strategy.
  // ------------------------
  $gameBoard.on("click", ".tile", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    // -------------------------
    // if this is not a mole do nothing...
    // -------------------------
    if (!$this.hasClass(mole_ClassName)) { return; }
    // -------------------------

    // -------------------------
    // "hide" this mole and increment the score
    // -------------------------
    $this.removeClass(mole_ClassName);
    gameScore += 1;
    // -------------------------
  });
  // ------------------------

  var startGame = function() {
    gameScore = 0;

    // -------------------------
    // Every turnTime, spawn a new mole.
    // Record moleInterval so we can cancel it when the game ends.
    // -------------------------
    moleInterval = setInterval(spawnMole, turnTime);
    // -------------------------

    // -------------------------
    // The game ends in gameTime
    // -------------------------
    setTimeout(endGame, gameTime);
    // -------------------------
  }

  var endGame = function() {
    // -------------------------
    // Stop spawning new moles
    // -------------------------
    clearInterval(moleInterval);
    // -------------------------

    // -------------------------
    // "hide" any existing moles.
    // -------------------------
    $gameTiles.removeClass(mole_ClassName);
    // -------------------------

    alert("Game Over! Score: " + gameScore);
  }

  var spawnMole = function(timeToLive) {
    // -------------------------
    // Select a random tile to set as a mole.
    // You might adjust to only spawn moles where there are none already.
    // -------------------------
    var $targetTile = $($gameTiles[getRandomIntInclusive(0, $gameTiles.length - 1)]);
    // -------------------------

    // -------------------------
    // Moles shall live for a random amount of time
    // -------------------------
    var timeToLive = getRandomIntInclusive(moleLifeMin , moleLifeMax);
    // -------------------------

    // -------------------------
    // "show" the mole
    // -------------------------
    $targetTile.addClass(mole_ClassName);
    // -------------------------

    // -------------------------
    // after timeToLive, automatically "hide" the mole
    // -------------------------
    setTimeout(function() { $targetTile.removeClass(mole_ClassName); }, timeToLive);
    // -------------------------
  }

  return {
    startGame
  };

}();

game.startGame();
```

```css
#gameBoard {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

#gameBoard .tile {
  background-color: black;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#gameBoard .tile.mole {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameBoard">
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own version of this game to help you out.

**Breakdown**

Start by creating variables to store the user's score, level and how many lives they have. Also create a boolean variable for whether or not the game is in progress. This prevents accidental re-clicks of the start game button.

We will be incrementing the score quite a bit, so it is best to create a re-usable function for that. In my example, this is the `displayScore()` function. In my game, as you gain points, you will level up, so the view needs to be updated to relect that. That's where the `levelUp()` function comes in handy.

In the game board there are 16 cells, arranged in a 4 x 4 matrix. We can query the collection of all the cells with `document.querySelectorAll(".cell")`. To make the game fun, it's better not to know which cell will pop-up. That's why a cell will randomly light up in the `randomCell()` function.

Throughout the game, there are multiple times when the script needs to check if the player has lost. Because of that, I created a reusable `gameOver()` function that counts the player's lives. If the player has no lives remaining, the interval will be cleared, the playing status will be reset to not playing and the variables will be reset.

Try it out here.

```js
var score = 0;
var level = 1;
var lives = 5;
var playing = false;

var start = document.getElementById("start");
var scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score-display");
var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

function displayScore() {
    levelUp();
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = "Score: " + score + "<span id='level-display'> Level: " + level + "</span><span id='lifes-display'> Lives: " + lives + "</span>";
}

function levelUp() {
    level = Math.max(Math.floor(score / 10), 1);
}

function randomCell() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
}

function gameOver() {
    if (lives === 0) {
        clearInterval(getCells);
        score = 0;
        level = 1;
        lives = 5;
        playing = false;
    }
}

function highlightCell() {
    var target = randomCell();
    var prevScore = score;
    cells[target].style.background = "green";
    setTimeout(function() {
     cells[target].style.background = "red";
        if (score === prevScore) {
            lives--;
            displayScore();
            gameOver();
        }
    }, 1000)
}

start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!playing) {
        playing = true;
        displayScore();
        getCells = setInterval(function() {
            highlightCell();
        }, 1500);
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (playing) {
            var cell = this;
            if (this.style.background === "green") {
                score++;
            }
            else {
                lives--;
                gameOver();
         }
            displayScore();
        }
    })
}
```

```css
#game-board {
  height: 330px;
  width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 21%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: red;
}

#game-info {
  height: 40px;
  width: 330px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

#level-display, #lifes-display {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#start { 
  margin: 10px 37%;
}
```

```html
<div id="game-info">
  <p id="score-display"></p>
</div>
  
<div id="game-board">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>

<button id="start">Start Game</button>
```